# MongoDB getting error while setting up at WAMP localhost for window

Tags: mongodb, window, localhost, wamp

I am setting up MongoDB on localhost WAMP,
when i hit the port number http://127.0.0.1:28017 getting following error:

It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

Please let me know how can i view database like phpmyadmin for MongoDB.

Comment: Native MongoDB hasn't any web interface, probably you want a Admin UI like these: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/

Answer (score 1):

`MongoDB` does not offer by default a Webinterface for Administration, so you have to use additional Software. I know that [`Adminer`](http://www.adminer.org/de/) also supports MongoDB.

Otherwise please read this Section in the [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) (which are really great for learning MongoDB. I haven't tried all of them, but i think Adminer will do the Jobs. The MongoDB Shell is also great.

Answer (score -1):

You can use cPanel too for this. cPanel server , because it is just another linux server.

Comment: setting up a new Server does not solve the problem he has and does also not answer the question for other users.